# Replace : with \n using sed

Tags: command-line, unix

I'm trying to output my $PATH in the command line, but also replace the : with \n using the following:

```
echo $PATH | sed s/:/\n/g
```

This doesn't work 100%, how to I get it working?

Comment: why `sed` ? doesn't `tr ':' '\n'` work ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment?

Comment: [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting): `echo "$PATH" | sed 's/:/\n/g'`

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a bash substitution: `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash, i.e.

```
echo $PATH | sed s/:/\\n/g
```

Or, as BatchyX noted

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

---

Another possibility, if you want to parse $PATH, you can also use

```
IFS=:
for i in $PATH; do
   echo $i
done
```

Here `IFS=:` tells `bash` to split strings at `:`. Please note, that this will alter other things in the current session, too. Excerpt from `man bash`:

> IFS    The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting
>   after expansion and to split lines  into  words
>                 with the read builtin command.  The default value is `<space><tab><newline>`

Comment: Doesn't the `:` need to be backslashed as well?

Comment: @pratnala: Don't think so... I tested the command successfully in bash and zsh.

Comment: When I run your first example in the cmd line, the colons are replaced, but with a literal \n, so my path isn't getting split to newlines at the colons.

Comment: But the second one works perfectly!

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk What was the problem with your original command (as in the question?)

Comment: @mpy I don't think you have to escape the backslash because `\n` as a whole represents the return character, isn't it? Escaping the backslash makes '\' and 'n' two separate characters

Comment: @pratnala: You can have a point, as my code does not work for the OP. But, when the shell reads the original command, it will replace `\n` by a literal `n` _before_ sed gets invoked. `echo \n` returns `n`. So when you use `\\n` in the command, the shell will pass `\n` to sed, which will in turn interpret that as newline. At least in my understanding. Frankly, I don't know why it's not working for Josef.

Comment: You need to escape the `\ ` because the sed pattern is not quoted. A more robust method would be @user1936123 answer below.

Comment: @terdon ah the quotes! forgot about them!

Comment: I'm on a Mac.  While your `tr` solution works for me, your `sed` solution doesn't.  Any ideas?

Comment: @A.Ellett: Sorry, I don't know MacOS and don't have access to a Mac. I only have in mind that older OS versions use `\r` as EOL -- but if that's an issue, the `tr` command shouldn't work either...

Answer (score 4):

You could also quote the regular expression:

`echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'`

For your \n literals, you could use `echo -e`.

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk: Does that command work for you? (I would assume it's identical to my first one -- \n gets passed directly to sed)